# Select y Update en SQLite con Android

Tags: android, sqlite, sqllite

Trato de guardar unos datos en base de datos SQLite y luego mostrarlos en una actividad pero por algún motivo hago algo mal.

Actividad "BD":

```
public class BD extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    String sqlCreate = "CREATE TABLE jugador (codigo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                         "nombre TEXT, " +
                          "direccion TEXT, " +
                           "edad INT, " +
                            "nivel INT, " +
                             "exp INT, " +
                              "sabiduria INT, " +
                               "sabirudialimite INT, " +
                                "explimite INT)";

    public BD(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(sqlCreate);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

}
```

Actividad "ResultadoActivity" donde guardo datos:

```
    //Abro la base de datos 'BD' en modo escritura
    BD jugador = new BD(this, "BD", null, 2);
    db = jugador.getWritableDatabase();

    puntosexp = 100;
    puntossabiduria = 5;
    nivel = 2;

    //Comrpuebo que la BD se abre correctamente
    if(db != null){ 
        Log.e("TAG-BD","OK"); //<- SI lo muestra
        db.execSQL("UPDATE jugador SET exp='" + puntosexp + "' " +
         "          AND sabiduria='" + puntossabiduria + "'  " +
          "         AND nivel='" + nivel + "'" +
           "        WHERE codigo = 1" );
    }
    db.close();
```

Actividad "Inicio" donde leo la DB:

```
       //Abro la base de datos 'BD' en modo escritura
        BD jugador = new BD(this, "BD", null, 2);
        db = jugador.getWritableDatabase();

        //Comrpuebo que la BD se abre correctamente
        if(db != null){
            //String[] args = new String[] {};
                Cursor c = db.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM jugador WHERE codigo = 1", null);
                Log.e("TAG-BD","ENTRO BD"); //<- SI lo muestra
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do { Log.e("TAG-Do"," Ok"); //<- No lo muestra
                        Log.e("TAG-2",""+c.getInt(6)); //<- No lo muestra
                        nivel_bd= c.getInt(5);
                        exp_bd = c.getInt(6);
                        sabiduria_bd = c.getInt(7);
                    } while(c.moveToNext());
                }
        }
        db.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas creando una base de datos, estas actualizando un registro donde `codigo = 1`:

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE jugador SET exp='" + puntosexp + "' " +
         "          AND sabiduria='" + puntossabiduria + "'  " +
          "         AND nivel='" + nivel + "'" +
           "        WHERE codigo = 1" );
```

Pero no has insertado algún valor en tu tabla donde el campo `codigo` tenga valor de 1. Por lo tanto al tratar de obtener datos con el query el cursor es vacio y no entra a obtener los datos.

```
...
...
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM jugador WHERE codigo = 1", null);
                Log.e("TAG-BD","ENTRO BD"); //<- SI lo muestra
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do { Log.e("TAG-Do"," Ok"); //<- No lo muestra
                        Log.e("TAG-2",""+c.getInt(6)); //<- No lo muestra
                        nivel_bd= c.getInt(5);
                        exp_bd = c.getInt(6);
                        sabiduria_bd = c.getInt(7);
                    } while(c.moveToNext());
                }
                ...
                ...
```